# Need help adjusting script to work only if the screen size is met

Tags: javascript, media-queries, typed.js

I'm using typed.js and I don't want it working on mobile. Here's my code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    // Typed Span Element
    $( window ).on( 'resize', function ( ) {
        var win = $( this );
        if ( win.width( ) < 765 ) {
            $( ".typed-element" ).typed( {
                strings: [ "Aim^1500" ],
                typeSpeed: 200,
                loop: false,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                // time before typing starts
                startDelay: 0,
                // backspacing speed
                backSpeed: 0,
                // time before backspacing
                backDelay: 500
            } );
        } else {
            $( ".typed-element" ).typed( {
                strings: [ "Aim^1500", "Game^1500", "Internet^1500" ],
                typeSpeed: 200,
                loop: true,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                // time before typing starts
                startDelay: 0,
                // backspacing speed
                backSpeed: 0,
                // time before backspacing
                backDelay: 500
            } );
        }
    } );

} );
```

If there's a way to totally stop the script that'd be even more ideal. My workaround right now is adjusting the strings to show only one word, that is if this code even worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading this on a mobile, then you know the window.width() before the javascript is initiated.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    // This is a mobile and there is no reason to activate the typed element.
    // return stops the processing of the rest of the code.
    if($(window).width() < 765 ) return 

    //This should NEVER be hit on a mobile and will be just fine on everything else.  
    // Typed Span Element
    $( window ).on( 'resize', function ( ) {
        var win = $( this );
        if ( win.width( ) < 765 ) {
            $( ".typed-element" ).typed( {
                strings: [ "Aim^1500" ],
                typeSpeed: 200,
                loop: false,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                // time before typing starts
                startDelay: 0,
                // backspacing speed
                backSpeed: 0,
                // time before backspacing
                backDelay: 500
            } );
        } else {
            $( ".typed-element" ).typed( {
                strings: [ "Aim^1500", "Game^1500", "Internet^1500" ],
                typeSpeed: 200,
                loop: true,
                showCursor: true,
                cursorChar: "|",
                // time before typing starts
                startDelay: 0,
                // backspacing speed
                backSpeed: 0,
                // time before backspacing
                backDelay: 500
            } );
        }
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the variables for the browsers height and width

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

If window.screen.availWidth is less than 765, it's a mobile.

```
if(window.screen.availWidth < 765){
    //your code here
}
```